# Elemental life forms in space

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I remember watching in Cartoon Netwoorks years ago maybe around the 2000's a cartoon about diferent alien races living in diferent planets where each race was related with an element like rock people, ice, people, fire people and another. I also remember that the first episodes where about their star dying and converting in a supernova killing their planets and they end escaping to the space in ships.

I have been years trying to find what cartoon was?

Comment: A popular one for ident questions. This is the third dupe :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is "[Shadow Raiders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Raiders)" from 1998-99. There's a strong emphasis on elemental races (fire, ice, rock & bone) facing off against a big bad enemy.

> Shadow Raiders is set in a five-planet solar system known as the
>   Cluster. The four habitable planets are in a constant state of war,
>   always raiding one another for resources unique to each planet.
>   However, when an alien named Tekla comes from another solar system,
>   she brings a warning: the Beast Planet is coming. Now Graveheart, a
>   humble miner of Planet Rock, must convince the leaders of Fire, Rock,
>   Bone, and Ice to put aside their differences and stand together
>   against the Beast, their new common enemy.

Comment: Yea, i think it is.Thanks a lot i have been looking for it for weeks!!

Comment: @HansyD.Solis - Nice one. Don't forget to upvote as well by clicking the upward-facing triangle to the left of the question...

Comment: I tried but it seems i dont have enough points sorry